# In Angular: on selecting option from dropdown I want to search in search field with that value

Tags: angularjs, dropdown, nssearchfield

I am new to angular and I am stuck...
I want to create a dropdown as shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eC4Zx.jpg) where the placeholder in the textbox depends on the selected option from the dropdown.

My html is

```
<select class="selectpicker" ng-options="search for search in searchCriteria" ng-model="searchWith">
    <option value="">Select : </option>
</select>

<input type="text" ng-model="searchName" class="form-control" placeholder="Search with {{searchWith}}" />
```

My controller is defined as:

```
var companyInfo = angular.module('companyInfo', []);

companyInfo.controller('searchExample', ['$scope',   '$http',function($scope, $http){
   $scope.searchCriteria = ['Name', 'Employee Id', 'Designation', 'Email','Phone No']

   $http.get("data/data.json").then(function(data){
       $scope.employeeDetails= data.data;       
   });

   $scope.searchInTable = function(searchName){
      $scope.searchVal = searchName;
   }    
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `data-ng-change` binds the event on change of select with the specified function

```
    <select class="selectpicker" ng-options="search for search in searchCriteria" ng-model="searchWith" data-ng-change="search()">
    <option value="">Select : </option>
</select>

<input type="text" ng-model="searchName" class="form-control" placeholder="Search with {{searchWith}}" />
```

and in your controller

```
    $scope.search = function(){
  $scope.searchName = $scope.searchWith;
}
```